# How to select Alternating column values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, alternating

I have list a data `ORDER BY DCREPORTTIME`.

My problem is I need to select the row which is alternating (ALARMSET/ALARMCLEARED).

Pls refer pic below... TQ~

**RED - no need to select.

```
shift     | LOCATIONNAME       | CALARMSTATE      | DCREPORTTIME
--------- ----------------------------------------------------------    
5/15/2013 | MYQ01_CTES_A_LTS   | **AlarmSet**     | 11:12:26
5/15/2013 | MYQ01_CTES_A_LTS   | **AlarmCleared** | 11:12:26
5/15/2013 | MYQ01_CTES_A_LTS 5 | AlarmCleared     | 11:12:53
5/15/2013 | MYQ01_CTES_A_LTS 5 | AlarmSet         | 14:57:38
5/15/2013 | MYQ01_CTES_A_LTS 5 | AlarmSet         | 14:57:43
5/15/2013 | MYQ01_CTES_A_LTS 5 | AlarmCleared     | 14:57:43
```

[Example data : HERE!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBlcv.gif)

Comment: what is the table schema and what have you tried, what is the desired output and what does the red color in your example screenshot mean

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
 Select  a.shift,a.LOCATIONNAME,a.DCREPORTTIME,a.CALARMSTATE
 from yourTable a
 inner join yourTable b
 on  a.CALARMSTATE <> b.CALARMSTATE and a.LOCATIONNAME=b.LOCATIONNAME
 and a.DCREPORTTIME= b.DCREPORTTIME
```

Demo in [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c91fd/7)

Comment: hi Praveen. thanks for reply. BUT, yes this is the output that I want. BUT, the DCREPORTTIME is not all date same.

Comment: @user2286756:Then what is criteria to reject the rows as shown in your diagram

Comment: Thats my proble... Currenly what I can se is ONLY LOCTIONNAME and ALARMSTATE must be alternating after sort the datetime. Posible sql : DATEPART(a.DCREPORTTIME,hh)= DATEPART(a.DCREPORTTIME,hh). But, gto error : "not a recognized datepart"

Comment: Your `DATEPART` function is wrong. It should be `DATEPART(hh,a.DCREPORTTIME)` instead of `DATEPART(a.DCREPORTTIME,hh)`

Comment: Oh i see... but still the result is not that I need.I already update the schema. The last 2 row is the example that i need to include in the output.